# Reference wanted - preservation of constructible sheaves (in classical topology) by all functors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, constructible-sheaves, six-operations

Hello,

Can anybody point to me a reference about the preservation of the derived bounded category of sheaves with constructible cohomology on the underlying classical (anayltic) space of a complex algebraic variety, with respect to the functors Verdier duality and push-forward (probably "!").

Note that I am aware of Kashiwara and Schapira book, but I would like some other reference which does not use this microlocalization things which I do not know.

Thank you,
Sasha

Answer (score 2):

You could try *Sheaves in Topology* by Alexandru Dimca. There are no prerequisites other than basic sheaf theory, so you don't have to worry about microlocal troubles or anything else.

Comment: I like this book a lot, but (like for most 'heavy' results) it doesn't actually give a proof, only references. Here is what Dimca writes immediately before Theorem 4.1.5., which says that $D^b_c(-)$ is closed under the six operations: "For the proof in the case *X*, *Y* smooth, see [Kashiwara and Schapira]. The singular case follows from [Borel], see also remark 4.1.7. below. The claim in (i)(b), the algebraic case, is in [Nori]. For a unified treatment, see [Schürmann]."

Comment: I could not find no where [Nori] though (not in my library, nor online).

Answer (score 0):

There is a new book *Perverse Sheaves and Applications to Representation Theory* by Pramod N. Achar, which is published in 2021. I think it contains all details you need and it does not use microlocal method.